# code coverage using emma plugin in hudson

Tags: ant

I am able to get instrumented classes, but I could not find my runtime coverage data. I'm getting the output in hudson using `build.xml(ant)`. Can anyone please help me out...The following is my build.xml file...

```
<path id="classpath.test">
    <pathelement location="${dir.dest}/test.jar"/>
<fileset dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext">
    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
</fileset>  
</path>     

<path id="emma.lib">
<pathelement location="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\emma-2.0.5312.jar" />    
<pathelement location="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\emma_ant-2.0.5312.jar" /> 
</path>     
<taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" classpathref="emma.lib" />          

<target name="compile" depends="init,prepare" >
<javac classpathref="classpath.test" debug="on"  srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${out.dir}" />

<emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" >
<instr instrpathref="run.classpath"  destdir="${out.instr.dir}"  metadatafile="${coverage.dir}/coverage.emma"  merge="true">
    <filter excludes="*Test*"/>
</instr>        
 </emma>
     </target>

     <target name="run" depends="jar">
<java classpathref="classpath.test" classname="MainArea" fork="true"/>
     </target> 

     <target name="junit" depends="run">
    <junit fork="true" haltonfailure="false" printsummary="yes" failureproperty="test.failed">

        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
         <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/src" />    
             <pathelement location="${out.instr.dir}" />     
             <pathelement location="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\junit-4.10.jar" />    
             <pathelement location="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\emma-2.0.5312.jar" />    
             <pathelement location="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\emma_ant-2.0.5312.jar" />
        </classpath> 
          <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
          <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest todir=".">
            <fileset dir="./workspace">
                <include name = "MainAreaTest.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.file=${coverage.dir}/coverage.emma"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.merge=true"/>     

    </junit>

    </target>

   <target name="emma.report"  depends="junit">

   <emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" verbosity="verbose"> 
 <report sourcepath="./workspace" >
 <fileset dir="${coverage.dir}" >
             <include name="*.emma" />
  </fileset> 

 <txt outfile="${coverage.dir}/coverage.txt"/>
            <html outfile="${coverage.dir}/coverage.html"/> 
    <xml outfile="${coverage.dir}/coverage.xml"/>
      </report>
   </emma> 

  </target>
  </project>
```

I got output like this....

compile:

```
[javac] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\.hudson\jobs\Code_Coverage\out

[instr] processing instrumentation path ...
[instr] instrumentation path processed in 78 ms
[instr] [7 class(es) instrumented, 0 resource(s) copied]
[instr] metadata merged into [C:\Users\.hudson\jobs\Code_Coverage\coverage\coverage.emma] {in 0 ms}
```

emma.report:

```
 [echo] emma   

 [report] [EMMA v2.0, build 5312 (2005/06/12 19:32:43)]

 [report] input data path:
 [report] {
 [report]   C:\Users\.hudson\jobs\Code_Coverage\coverage\coverage.emma
 [report] }
 [report] source path:
 [report] {
 [report]   C:\Users\.hudson\jobs\Code_Coverage\workspace
 [report] }
 [report] processing input file [C:\Users\.hudson\jobs\Code_Coverage\coverage\coverage.emma] ...
 [report]   loaded 7 metadata entries
 [report] 1 file(s) read and merged in 0 ms
 [report] nothing to do: no runtime coverage data found in any of the data files
```

Comment: Is MainAreaTest really directly in ./workspace dir?

Comment: thanks for ur reply.And yes MainAreaTest is in ./workspace only.I need the exact code for running junit testcases on the instrumented classes,so that i can get .ec file(runtime coverage data)...Kindly guide me..we are in the middle of the deployment..

Comment: tests need .class files, not .java files

Comment: Instrumentation doesnt require Junit testcase right?thats why i have excluded "*Test*"(junit testcase).I need to run junit on instumented classes(.class files)....

Comment: in batchtest 'include name = "MainAreaTest.java"' is wrong. This should point to a compiled junit class. And you are right you only istrument the classes under test.

Comment: hi ...i have changed that "MainAreaTest.java" to "MainAreaTest.class",still am getting same error."No runtime coverage data found in any of the data files"

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include the .ec file to generate your report.

```
<emma enabled="${emma.enabled}" verbosity="verbose"> 
 <report sourcepath="./workspace" >
   <fileset dir="${coverage.dir}" >
     <include name="*.emma" />
     <include name="*.ec" />
   </fileset> 

   <txt outfile="${coverage.dir}/coverage.txt"/>
   <html outfile="${coverage.dir}/coverage.html"/> 
   <xml outfile="${coverage.dir}/coverage.xml"/>
 </report>
```